# Deploy multiple node.js containers of the same application during scaling using docker/k8s

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, docker-swarm, orchestration

For every 10K new users, we need to spawn a new application that processes that new set of users, based on some `env` variable (i.e. `offset: n`)

I tried using `docker-compose`, but it looks like I manually have to create `yml` processes for each container, which does not help much.

Can I use k8s, or some other tool, so that I can dynamically deploy an application with a dynamically set `env` property, so that my application will know which block of users to serve?

Ideally, I would like to have a master node (could be a lambda function, or an EC2 instance) that based on some registration event figures out if a new instance needs to be deployed, and it notifies the orchestrator to build a new deployment with some specific `env` variable.

Comment: Can you use something like the Kubernetes HorizontalPodAutoscaler to scale based on actual load, rather than number of users?  That would be able to run autonomously; you wouldn't have a "hard" separation between groups of users, but you're already suggesting a fairly large group of users per replica.

Answer (score 1):

A Kubernetes [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) can do something similar to this.  Each replica of the StatefulSet has a unique hostname, of the form `name-0`, `name-1`, and so on (guaranteed to begin with 0 and to be in order).  You could then find this in something like an entrypoint wrapper script:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
# (run this script as your image's ENTRYPOINT)

if [ -z "$OFFSET" ]; then
  OFFSET=$(hostname | sed -ne 's/.*-\([0-9][0-9]*\)$/\1/p')
fi
if [ -z "$OFFSET" ]; then
  echo could not determine shard offset >&2
  exit 1
fi

exec "$@"
```

A StatefulSet comes with other properties which you may or may not want; for example, updating an `image:` will cause the underlying Pods to be recreated in a very specific order.

A StatefulSet does include a way to [send a request to a specific replica](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#stable-network-id) but Kubernetes in and of itself will not know how to route requests for you; your client code would have to do this on its own.

Comment: Interesting, I assume I can get each replica's id within my client code and just scale using statefulSet replicas on demand. Thank you for your answer, I will give that a go and I will mark your answer as solved as soon as I manage to get a statefulset up and running